# how to know which cells (row & section) of a UITableView are currently being displayed?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is there a way to know which rows/sections are being displayed inside a UITableView ? I know I can use the function :

```
tableView:(UITableView *) tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But, this doesnt help me. For any given moment, I want to know which row/sections are being displayed and do some processing based on that.

Can anyone kindly help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At any given moment, you can retrieve the visible cells from the table view, or index paths :

`-(NSArray *)visibleCells;`
`-(NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows;`

Check [UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: For some reason after using `[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)tempArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];` `indexPathsForVisibleRows` is returning indexPaths for rows that aren't actually visible yet (i.e. I've added them to the bottom of the table which happens to already have been scrolled to the bottom, so adding them means they're off screen). I was planning on using this function to help me figure out if I needed to scroll the tableView up or not, now this task is more difficult :\